# User enters numbers separated by spaces, tabs, or new lines

Tags: java, eclipse

I am in an beginner java programming class and am stuck on something I know should be simple, but it's killing me. The user is prompted to enter any number of x,y values and can be entered separated by a space, a tab, or a new line. So it can be entered like this:

```
1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 etc...
```

or

```
1.0 (tab) 1.0 (tab) 2.0 (tab) 2.0 (tab) etc...
```

or

```
1.0 1.0
2.0 2.0
3.0 3.0
```

etc...

Well that's fine and great but I don't know how to separate these numbers. I'm thinking of having an x var and a y var and would like to separate them into this, but how do I do this? My first thought was maybe an array but we haven't even covered those yet. I feel like this is ridiculously easy and I'm just missing it

Answer (score 0):

If you take the input as a String you could do something like

```
String[] input = inputString.split(" ");
```

Then convert each element to your desired type.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a regular expression for this - find all white space in the string, then split on that.

```
String[] vals = t1.split("[\\s]+");
```

`\s` is the [whitespace character regex search pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Answer (score 0):

You can split a string up by space using the following:

```
String[] parts = userinput.split(" ");
```

You can split a string up by tab using the following:

```
String[] parts = userinput.split("\t");
```

You can split a string up by line return using the following:

```
String[] parts = userinput.split("\n");
```

note: you may beed to add a '/r' to the above \n

So, find your delimiter, split your string by that using one of the above (or more if needed)

then you should have all your data in a String array

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you to use scanner. You can set your delimeters that can be entered.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("This is a , test word \n ");
s.useDelimiter(",|\\n");
while(s.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. `[ \t]` is a regular expression meaning either a space or a tab.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String line = br.readLine();
  while (line != null && !line.isEmpty())
  {
    String[] arr = line.split("[ \t]");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2)
    {
      doSomething(Double.parseDouble(arr[i]), Double.parseDouble(arr[i+1]));
    }
    line = br.readLine();
  }
}

static void doSomething(double x, double y)
{
  System.out.println("x is "+x+", y is "+y);
}
```

You may want to also include some error checking.

Answer (score 0):

you can use BufferedReader + Scanner to read data that are separated by spaces or newlines:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Scanner input = new Scanner(br);
```

& read the numbers one by one using Scanner , which will wait until it meets a number then read it no matter what is separating them a space or a new line

```
int numbersCount = 5; //numbersCount is the count of the numbers you are wanting to read from the input , so if you are waiting 5 numbers then it will be 5. 
int[] numbers = new int[numbersCount];
for (int i=0;i<numbersCount;i++) 
{
  numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

> so the array numbers will contain all the numbers you want isA

hope this helps